# Function onChange for Checkbox in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I want to know is it possible to access the next or prev element in ReactJs?I have two `inputs` by labels  `a` and `b`.In `handlerChecked` function I want to check the attribute `checked` of both inputs.For example I checked  `a` and I want also to check `b` was checked or not. How can I do it?

```
class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
       .
       .
       .

handlerChecked = (e, elem) => {
    let isChecked = e.target.checked
    let value = e.target.value
    let checknext = e.target.next('input').checked //In this part I want to check the attribute checked of other Input//// 
}

.
.
.
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" className="" value="0" onChange={this.handlerChecked} /> <label><span>a</span></label>
            <input type="checkbox" className="" value="1" onChange={this.handlerChecked} /> <label><span>b</span></label>

        </div>
    )
}
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('Result'))
```

Comment: You should not work with DOM Elements directly. It's not how React works. What you should do is to use `state` and `props` to handle VirtualDOM updates. React will make all DOM updates for you.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no, React doesn't work that way, you can't go up and down an element's ancestor's tree to find sibling elements.

A common way to implement this feature is to give each checkbox a `name` attribute.

For example:

```
  <div>
    <input name="check1" type="checkbox"  onChange={this.handlerChecked} checked={this.state.check1} /> <label><span>a</span></label>
    <input name="check2" type="checkbox" onChange={this.handlerChecked} checked={this.state.check2} /> <label><span>b</span></label>
</div>
```

handle these two checkboxes with one handler

```
const handlerChecked = (e) => {
  const {name, checked} = e.target
  this.setState({
    [name]: checked
  })
}
```

then in your state keep track of those 2 names like this:

```
this.state = {
 check1: false,
 check2: false
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mxdi9i7 for your answer , But I did not get how I can check the attribute `checked` of each input by your code.

Comment: The point is to have state properties for the all checkboxes. You shouldn't work with DOM elements directly, you're killing all React's optimizations for render and reconciliation process.

Comment: @sahar when you invoke the onChange listener on the checkbox, the callback function handlerChecked will be called with a parameter `e`, that's the event of change. From that `e` you can find the target and thus the `checked` value of that checkbox. You can see the implementation from the second code block.

Comment: @sahar glad I helped! Kindly accept my answer if it solves your question.